# Where can I find detail specification for a certain opengl es extension?

Tags: opengl-es

Take gles extension *OES_EGL_image_external* for instance, here is the registry page:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_EGL_image_external.txt

In the registry, it says:

> For OpenGL ES 2.0 add a new section: "3.7.14 External Textures," which
>    follows section "3.7.13 Texture Objects."  For OpenGL ES 1.1 add a new
>    section after section "3.7.11 Texture Objects."

But, where to find this section? I searched all versions of gles 2.0 specification, still missing this "3.7.14". Where is it? Is the content right after this declaration what I am looking for?

Comment: "Is the content right after this declaration what I am looking for?" Yup.

Comment: Well, it's an extension, so it's of course not documented in the core spec. What you're looking at **is** the official specification of the extension.